# Why won't ubuntu install on my Hp6910 Laptop?

Tags: system-installation

I have tried almost everything and Ubuntu will not install on my laptop. I am using the bootable usb method thus far and when I insert the flash drive in and change the boot order to flash drive the laptop powers up and asks what language you want ubuntu to install and I select however from there the entire thing just locks up. I dont know what to do, The laptop I am attempting to install it on has no OS on it and that hard drive is brand new. I've tested the HD and it passes. What would cause the installation to lock up?

Answer (score 2):

you can try with Alternative install cd 
       it is a ubuntu non graphical install cd. it gives you more advance options 
       same problem happened to me as well i tried this.
                [click here to download it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in [more than one place](http://askubuntu.com/a/251836/22949). When tempted to do so, typically: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.